# CentOS 6.0 only shows loopback address with ifconfig

Tags: centos

I am trying to figure out whether a performance problem we are having with one of our processes is OS related. I installed CentOS 6.0 on a server which previously had CentOS 6.5 installed. Now when I do `ifconfig -a` it only shows the loopback address. There are two network cards on the server. And they did show up in the previous version. Any ideas?

EDIT: Adding `dmesg` and `lspci` outputs:

[image: dmesg]

[image]

Comment: Could you add output of the "dmesg | grep -i eth" to the question? Also add output of the "lspci -v" related to network cards

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly a driver problem. Is seems centos 6.0's kernel isn't shipped with your card's drivers.

The command `lsmod` will list you the currently loaded kernel modules among which are the loaded hardware drivers.

Download from here : http://www.broadcom.com/support/license.php?file=NXII/linux-7.6.62.zip and install from USB key if you can.

Comment: I installed the drivers. But still the NICs don't show up.

Comment: Still nothing new in `dmesg` ? weird. Try to load modules manually with `modprobe` maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

The necessary driver `tg3` doesn't appear to have been present in RHEL/CentOS 6.0. The first release in which it documented as present is 6.1. And the current 6.x version at the time of your post was 6.5. Update your system.